Does the performance impact even happen on simple select from view with where clause of it isn't used in JOINS?
I'm trying to understand effect of querying views over linked server.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/sql/database-engine/linked-servers/decreased-performance-linkedserver-views
The examples show that statistics aren't picked up when firing such query. Whether we do select * from linkedserver.db.tbl.viewname or select * from linkedserver.db.tbl.viewname where col1='test', the statistics is an issue.
I can imagine this is a problem if we do a join between the views or between the view and local table, because the engine on the server where this is executing will have wrong statistics, therefore will choose a poor execution plan.
But for a simple query like this, which has no joins, but possibly has the joins within the view, is there any performance impact? I'm unable to understand why statistics will matter if the query is as simple as the below:
select * from linkedserver.db.tbl.viewname or select * from linkedserver.db.tbl.viewname where col1='test'
For specifically the above queries, the stats will say 10000, so what can go wrong? Nothing if the query is guaranteed to run on the linked server. But is it deterministic to know where this query will run?

I think the inside of the view can be very complex, so the engine can't get the statistics for each table within the view. But as the documentation says, you can add an index to the view, which will make the optimizer work normal.

Isn't the view executed on the linked server?

@RodgerKong Only a specific subset of views indexing is applicable for. Less likely on complex views.

The problem is not where to execute, but how to get estimated number of rows. Query remote table directly, statistics can be read from remote, local server can use less roundtrip to get data. For remote view, local server can only assume a number of return rows, without WHERE clause, it's 10K; with WHERE clause, it's 100 or 1K. This causes poor performance, and that's why use indexed views will be fine, although there are many limitations.

I get your point is valid for joins with local tables. But does the engine also get to decide where the WHERE clause must execute?

For
select * from linkedserver.db.tbl.viewname where col1='test'
How do you know which server will evaluate the col1='test' predicate?
There's an answer, but the fact that it's not obvious means that you should normally use OPENQUERY or EXEC(query) at linkedserver to explicitly control what queries are executed by which server, and what data is exchanged between linked servers.

If there is JOIN involved then it makes sense, but for a simple select query with where clause isn't there guarantee it will get executed on the linked sever?

Nope.  That query must run with the collation semantics of a local query.  See https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/sql-server-support-blog/how-it-works-linked-servers-and-collation-compatibility/ba-p/315460 So you can figure that out, and somehow document the behavior and the required linked server configuration for posterity,  OR you can always use pass-through queries that obviously execute entirely at the remote server.


I'm unable to understand why statistics will matter if the query is as simple as ... select * from linkedserver.db.tbl.viewname where col1='test'

Why would this query be inefficient if it were run against a local table?
Depending on how up-to-date the statistics were, the database might or might not choose to use an index defined on col1.
No index implies a table scanning (slow) query.
Also, if the measured cardinality were "off", it might also choose a sub-optimal execution plan.
It is generally accepted that statistics on linked tables are less accurate than those on local ones.  Worst of all, as that article says, the Optimiser is given a "bad" (or, at least, hard-coded) cardinality estimate to work with.  It's trying its best to put together a decent execution plan, but having to do so based on [intentionally] misleading metadata.

Where clause will be evaluated on the linked server so how is this same as the article?
